# Creating an assymmetric key inside SQL server to access a DLL fails

Tags: sql-server

I need to access a DLL (C#) from SQL trigger for one of our requirements. I have compiled the DLL and could load it in SQL server space by using the "Create Assembly" and then create a trigger for it.

The I have set the database to be trust worthy by setting the `TRUSTWORTHY` flag `ON`.

```
ALTER DATABASE %DBName% SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
```

But after realizing that this  is unsafe way of doing it, I have signed the DLL with a key (`.snk` file) and tried to create an asymmetric key and then create a login based on the key, for whom I can grand external access. Either without setting DB as trustworthy or unless I create a user who can access the DLL using the key, I cannot use the DLL because it performs a file access. Hence the DLL has to be loaded with an external access permission. But while doing the below query to create the asymmetric key, I am getting an error which follows the query,

```
USE [master];
GO
  CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY [ClrPermissionsKey]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = 'D:\Trigger\TriggerManager.dll'
```

> "Msg 15208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>
> The certificate, asymmetric key, or private key file does not exist or
>   has invalid format."
>
> The .snk file lies in the same path as the DLL. Requesting your help
>   here.
>
> If this is not the correct way of doing it, please suggest.